# Multiple conditions in ternary operators

Tags: java, operator-keyword, ternary

First off, the question is "Write a Java program to find the smallest of three numbers using ternary operators."

Here's my code:

```
class questionNine
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
        int smallestNum;

        smallestNum = (x<y && x<z) ? x : (y<x && y<z) ? y : (z<y && z<x) ? z;
        System.out.println(smallestNum + " is the smallest of the three numbers.");
    }
}
```

I tried to use multiple conditions in the ternary operator but that doesn't work. I was absent a few days so I'm not really sure what to do and my teacher's phone is off. Any help?

Comment: try it but instead of the last test, just put ":z"

Comment: At least in my experienced, just because you *can* write chained ternary statements, doesn't mean you *should*. Also, what you have so far is very complicated, you should only need to compare the variables to one another once: `int smallest = min(min(x, y), z)`.

Comment: Math.min uses the ternary operator. the simplest is to staticly import this method and write `smalledNum = min(x, min(y, z))`

Comment: Consider modifying the assignment for the likely event when the professor makes "three" a variable. This will likely get you extra credit.

Answer (score 36):

Try

```
int min = x < y ? (x < z ? x : z) : (y < z ? y : z);
```

You can also remove the parenthesis:

```
int min = x < y ? x < z ? x : z : y < z ? y : z;
```

Comment: Parentheses-free version looks like an entry to Obfuscated-C competition.

Comment: Why does adding extra paranthesis gives error: unexpected type
`int min = x < y ? ((x < z) ? x : z) : ((y < z) ? y : z);`

Answer (score 14):

Since this is homework I'm not just going to give you the answer, but instead an algorithm so that you can work it out yourself.

First work out how to write min(x, y) using a single ternary operator.

Once you have that, change the following code for min(x, y, z) to use a ternary operator then substitute in the code for min(x, y) that you worked out from the previous step.

```
int min(x, y, z) {
    if (x <= y) {
        return min(x, z);
    } else {
        return min(y, z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're testing for z, when you really don't need to. Your ternary operator must be of form cond ? ifTrue : ifFalse;

so if you have multiple conditions, you have this:

cond1? ifTrue1 : cond2? if True2 : ifFalse2;

If you understand this, don't look below. If you still need help, look below.

I also included a version that doesn't nest them that is clearer (assuming you don't need to have them nested. I sure would hope your assignment doesn't require you to nest them because that's pretty ugly!)

.

.

Here's what I come up with:

```
class QuestionNine
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        smallest(1,2,3);
        smallest(4,3,2);
        smallest(1,1,1);
        smallest(5,4,5);
        smallest(0,0,1);
    }

    public static void smallest(int x, int y, int z) {
        // bugfix, thanks Mark! 
        //int smallestNum = (x<y && x<z) ? x : (y<x && y<z) ? y :  z;
        int smallestNum = (x<=y && x<=z) ? x : (y<=x && y<=z) ? y :  z;
        System.out.println(smallestNum + " is the smallest of the three numbers.");
    }

    public static void smallest2(int x, int y, int z) {
       int smallest = x < y ? x : y; // if they are equal, it doesn't matter which
       smallest = z < smallest ? z : smallest;
       System.out.println(smallest + " is the smallest of the three numbers.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int min(int x, int y, int z) {
    return x<y?Math.min(x, z):Math.min(y, z);           
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int smallestNum = min(10, 12, 15);
    System.out.println(smallestNum);
}
```

Comment: I like this implementation. Let the libraries do the work

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late. Just for information this also works:

```
int smallestNum = (x<y ? x : (x=y)) < z ? x : z
```

Comment: It's mutating the data, though, but I can see this working

Answer (score 1):

The last part: `(z<y && z<x) ? z` is missing a ':' :

```
(z<y && z<x) ? z : some_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
    int smallestNum = (x < y && x < z) ? x :
        (y < x && y < z) ? y :
        (z < y && z < x) ? z:y;
    System.out.println(smallestNum + " is the smallest of the three numbers.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My contribution ...

```
public static int getSmallestNumber( int x, int y, int z) {

     return x < y && x < z ? x : y < x && y < z ? y : z;
}

public static void main ( String ... args ) {

    System.out.println( getSmallestNumber( 123, 234, 345 ) );
}
```

Comment: Returns 2 when it is called with parameters (3,2,1)

Comment: @fthdgn ~ Good Catch... Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the number and check heigest number of three number:-");
    int a=sc.nextInt();
    int b=sc.nextInt();
    int c=sc.nextInt();
    int max;
    max=(a>b&&a>c)?a:(b>a&&b>c)?b:(c>a&&c>b)?c:(a==b&&b==c)?a:0;
    
    System.out.println("the heigest number is:"+max);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is coming in seven years late, so I'll just give you the code:

```
int smallestNumber = (x > y) ? 
            ((y > z) ? z : y) : 
            ((x > z) ? z : x);
```

The indentation should explain the code, which is simply a ternary that evaluates other ternaries on the initial condition `x > y`; /* the first ternary gets evaluated if that condition is true, else the second one gets evaluated. */

Answer (score 0):

you missed the value after z var
smallestNum = (x<y && x<z) ? x : (y<x && y<z) ? y : (z<y && z<x) ? z:0;
Try this, it works

Answer (score 0):

```
public class questionNine{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
    int smallestNum =  (x<y && x<z) ? x : ((y < x && y<z) ? y : z);
    System.out.println(smallestNum);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int min = (x<y)?((x<z)?x:z):((y<z)?y:z);
```

Answer (score -1):

best way to do this is to make an example using if and else statement and then apply the ternary operators on it
 (q

Comment: Please add some more details in your answer