# How to rewrite multiple ternary "? :" in terms of "if" statements?

Tags: java

I understand that:

```
value = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

is the same as:

```
if (a > b)
  value = a;
else
  value = b;
```

But I'm having trouble deciphering what this means:

**EDIT** (the previous example I used was not good, this is real code from another example):

```
Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
      : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
          : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
```

How do I rewrite the last equation in terms of `if`, `else if`, and `else`?

Comment: It's uncompilable statement.

Comment: Well, it's straight out of this [example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/). Maybe Google wrote something uncompilable, but it seems like those chances are slim. **Edit** The letters `a` through `d` and the comparator `>` are ones I made up, but I'm really just asking about the `? :`.

Comment: To expand on what @IvanBabanin said, the first condition implies that `a` and `b` are non-`boolean` variables, but that leaves the condition of the second conditional incomplete.

Comment: I think everyone is missing the point of the actual question. I just want to know about the `? :`. I've edited the example.

Comment: A good place to start would be to think of things like this as a nested conditional: `<condition1> ? <something1> : (<condition2> ? <something2> : (<condition3> ? <something3> : <something4>))`

Comment: The conditional could be roughly translated from `<condition> ? <something1> : <something2>` to `if (condition) then <something1> else <something2>`

Comment: OMG, refactor it! Only use `? :` in a short, single line statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So based on the [example you linked](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/):

```
Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
      : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
          : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
```

Which you seemed to have used to produce `value = (a > b) ? a : b ? c : d;`, which should probably be more like, `value = (a == b) ? c : (a == d) ? e : f`, it would read something like...

```
Tracker t = null;
if (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) {
    t = analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
} else if ((trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER)) {
    t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
} else {
    t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is exactly what I was asking about. That previous example I made up was bad and it was purely because I didn't understand `? :`.

Answer (score 11):

You need a second conditional for this ternary expression to work.

```
value = (a > b) ? a : (b > c) ? c : d;
```

Then it would become:

```
if (a > b) {
    value = a;
} else if (b > c) {
    value = c;
} else {
    value = d;
}
```

**In your case:**

```
if (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) {
    t = analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
} else if (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) {
    t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
} else {
    t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
}
```

**Resources:**

- [Multiple conditions in ternary operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986654/multiple-conditions-in-ternary-operators)

Comment: Looks like you and @MadProgrammer both had the same answer. I'm just going with the earlier one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, +1 for both of you for your patience and clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Use an IDE like Eclipse that offers the possibility to automatically rewrite ternary operators as ifs. `Ctrl + 1` opens the quick fix shown below.

[image]

Comment: Wow! That is an amazing hidden tool! Thanks! :)

Comment: Cool stuff @cypressious